# AKKA Remoting lookup remote actors fails when hostname is used

Tags: remoting, lookup, actor, akka

I have been using the AKKA remoting feature. It has been working very well except for one issue. If I try to lookup a remote actor based on its hostname, the lookup fails. However, if I do it based on IP address it works fine. Is there any way to make it work uniformly for both hostname and IP address ?

My application.conf is something like below:

```
akka {
  version = "2.0.2"
  actor {
    provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
  }
  remote {
    transport = "akka.remote.netty.NettyRemoteTransport"
    netty {
        ...
      use-passive-connections = off
      hostname = ""
      port = 8000
        ...
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

From another machine:

```
actorSystem.actorFor("akka://MyActorSystem@10.0.0.1:8000/user/MyActor")  //**Works**
actorSystem.actorFor("akka://MyActorSystem@hostname.abc.com:8000/user/MyActor") //**Fails**
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this behavior as well.  I expected the Akka actor system to pick up the system host name from `java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost.getHostName`.

However this does not always seem to work.  On the upside, adding the hostname to your application.conf file should produce the correct result, allowing remote connections looked up via `context.actorFor("akka://host.domain.com:8000/user/whatever")`.

Even when the `InetAddress` call above produces the desired host name string, e.g. as easily checked in the Scala REPL, Akka seems to prefer binding to the IP Address.  If you want Akka to bind to the alias automatically on system start you might consider modifying your Config object (set `akka.remote.netty.hostname`) before passing it to `ActorSystem.apply`.

Of course the other, perhaps less desirable, option is to simply set the value on each of your deployed nodes.

Hope that helps!